# Create dynamic proxies on System.Type

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection

I have `List<Type>`, here Type is interface which i got using reflection.
So how to create the wcf proxy using channnel factory on these Type.

like:

```
foreach(Type t in types)
{
t proxy = ChannelFactory<t>.CreateChannel(new NetTcpBinding(), 
             new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress));
}
```

Here t is interface but the above code is giving compiler error.Can anybody tell me how to create wcf service proxy on Type.

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection and call the method `Type.MakeGenericType`:

```
foreach (Type t in types)
{
    Type genType = typeof(ChannelFactory<>).MakeGenericType(t);

    MethodInfo createChannelMethod = genType.GetMethod("CreateChannel", 
                                        new[] { typeof(Binding),
                                                typeof(EndpointAddress) });

    var proxy = createChannelMethod.Invoke(
                                null, 
                                BindingFlags.Static, 
                                null, 
                                new object[] { 
                                    new NetTcpBinding(), 
                                    new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress) 
                                }, 
                                null);
}
```

Comment: Thx for the quick reply.While using the above code im getting compiler error as "No best types found for implicitly typed array".

Comment: I have updated my answer. just write `new object[]` instead of `new[]`

Comment: Got solved by making it as new object[]{ new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress) }